# stackable trait pattern not work - cannot modify actor's recieve method

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I have a actor hierarchy which I would like to test for error scenarios - actually test a applied supervisors strategies. I need to modify an actor's receive method - for a message to fail the actor. I found a stackable trait pattern but cannot make it work. My code follows:

```
trait FailActor extends Actor {

  abstract override def receive = LoggingReceive {
     fail.orElse(super.receive)
  }
  def fail:Receive = {
    case "fail" => throw new RuntimeException("Test")
  }
}

class AddressTranslatorFailActor(storage: ActorRef) extends AddressTranslatorActor(storage) with FailActor
```

And in the test passing this failing actor:

```
val probe = TestProbe()
  val addressServiceProps = Props {
    new AddressServiceActor {
      override def translateAddressProps = classOf[AddressTranslatorFailActor]
    }
  }
```

where AddressService acctor is defined as follows:

```
class AddressServiceActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  def translateAddressProps: Class[_<:AddressTranslatorActor] = classOf[AddressTranslatorActor]
...
```

But still getting the "fail" message un-handeled.
Any hints?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I had a similar problem some time ago, and using props like in `Props[YourActorClass with YourBehaviorTrait]` doesn't stack the behavior while `Props(new YourActorClass with YourBehaviorTrait)` does stack the behavior into receive.

Comment: Overriding Props(... ) that I was trying to avoid because passing several arguments etc. So I tried just to pass a Class and construct props in the parent actor who actually creates this one. Seems that there is no way to avoid that.

Comment: @kaktusito I tried the suggested approach:  override def AddressTranslatorProps(adr: Address) = Props(new AddressTranslatorFailActor(storage))  but still getting AddressTranslatorFailActor] akka://testsystem/user/AddressService/$a - received unhandled message fail
Redefined AddressServiceActor to def AddressTranslatorProps(adr: Address) = Props(classOf[AddressTranslatorActor], storage) 
Seems like I cannot find a single way to do it

Comment: Take a look at the answer that I gave here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341337/strategy-pattern-in-akka.  It's not the accepted answer, but it might be something close to what you need.

Comment: @cmbaxter Thanks. One thing is not still clear to me: Why it doesn't work?