# Compose more than one receive function in Akka Actors

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming, composition

I have an Akka Actor that manages some messages, like `Find`, `Query`, that forward a new message to others types of actors. These actors will respond with new types of messages.

```
class Actorbase extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
     /* The two message below are related to each other */
     case Find(coll, id) => // Do something
     case QueryAck(key, value, u) => // Do something
     /* The three message below are related to each other */
     case Upsert(collection, id, value) => // Do something
     case Response.UpsertNAck(key, msg, u) => // Do something
     case Response.UpsertAck(key, u) => // Do something
     /* And so on... */
  }
}
```

In the above example, `QueryAck` is the response message of the forward of a message of type `Find`. `UpsertNAck` and `UpsertAck` are possible responses to an `Upsert` message.

To make the code more readable and maintainable, I wish to group the two sets of `case`s in two dedicated methods, i.e. `manageQueries` and `manageUpserts`, obtaining something similar to the following code.

```
class Actorbase extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
     manageQueries.andThen(manageUpserts)
  }
}
```

Is is possible? May I need to declare more than one method returning a `Receive` object and then compose them in some way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Receive` is just a type alias for `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`, so you can just define such anywhere and combine them using `f1 orElse f2`:

```
val manageQueries: Receive = { case ... }
val manageUpserts: Receive = { case ... }

def receive = manageQueries.orElse(manageUpserts)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you think it is better the approach I described in the question or the one exposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681444/composing-trait-behavior-in-scala-in-an-akka-receive-method?rq=1) SO answer?

Comment: This is better than the other one I think (as a maintainer of the project)